# Will I be warned when I am close to be blocked from asking?

Tags: support, post-ban

Will I be warned when I'm close to be a question ban?

I feel like I'll be on that side again after asking a not so unclear, question with the C++ tag. And, last time, I wasn't warned at all, so, I want to know.

It seems like a lot of questions are asking *why* but I've already been around for a while, It's the *when* am asking for.

Comment: What do you mean by prevented? It doesn't make sense to be prevented from asking before you are blocked from asking.. they both achieve the same result, no?

Comment: We cant know the when. By design. (if you DO mean how close to the ban you are.... This isnt the clearest question...)

Comment: @Rob sorry for that confusion. actually "prevent" in Fr is somehow "warned", hence my typo... Question edited...

Comment: I was about to post with "prévenir" in mind. In any case... I think you may get a warning before the ban kicks in the first time, but if you're hovering on the threshold,i dont think it'll keep on reminding you.

Comment: If you are so worried about being banned, then perhaps you should not have gone and asked more unclear questions? Oui?

Comment: @JK. actually, the *Oui?* should have been *Non?*. And I am not worried, just asking if warnings exist. So, It looks like you're missing the point here, Non ?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: yes and no.

Long answer: I joined SO a looong time ago when I knew virtually nothing about android development or programming in general. When I joined, I started posting questions instantly: anything I couldn't find an answer to with a quick google search I would post. Of course, it only took a few months for me to get banned, but I didn't even realize it was possible for that to happen. A while ago I noticed the ban had mysteriously vanished, and I started using this account again, but a lot more carefully.

The algorithm that bans people is probably based on your upvote/downvote ratio - if you're rep is increasing, you're probably good. But the system is kind of unfair since if you post noob questions (like mine) that are likely to get downvoted, you will be banned without even being told what you're doing wrong, save for a complementary message about posting things useful to the community not just yourself. Of course, I probably deserved it. I mean, "How to load a url into a webview when enter is pressed?" isn't exactly useful.

Comment: Couple of things here:a) no unfairness... It's YOUR job when you post to make sure its on topic. It's not like what is on topic and how to ask a good question isnt documented...  B) it is based on your question asking record. Not necessarily on your rep. Your rep might be increasing but your question record might be abysmal enough that it won't matter.

Comment: @Patrice While I generally agree, what James mentioned is pretty fair. They had two 0-score questions before the -5 which got them question banned. There was no feedback on the first two questions whatsoever. No comments, no downvotes, no closure. Both of them got an accepted answer, too. It's hard to say someone should have known their question was bad when *no one on the site told them it was* until they posted the question which puts them over the threshold. Yes, we can parrot the same old 'you should have taken the tour' and shift the blame to the users, but that's not helpful at all.

Comment: @Rob i definitely agree that people giving you feedback is nice. Nice != mandatory. I never asked a question here when i started coding because i lurked meta, i went on the help center, i made sure to understand the site. It is the poster's responsibility to do that. If they don't, its obviously better if a seasoned member takes the time to coach them. It shouldnt be a necessity, and it shouldnt replace new users doing their due diligence

Comment: @Patrice probably worth pointing out here that I had no clue there was a meta community when I started - someone gave me a link to this site, I made an account, I started using it. And to be fair your first comment was a bit obsolete (read the last two sentences).